# ubuntu 12.04 usb audio card roland duo-capture not recognized

Tags: sound, usb, alsa

I need high quality usb audio card for ubuntu 12.04 PCs so I bought Roland Duo-Capture which is very promising.
the problem is that with:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

I can see only the integrated audio card

```
0 snd_hda_intel
```

While issuing the

```
lsusb
```

I see the device:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0582:012b Roland Corp.
```

Is there a way to have ALSA understand this is an audio card?
If there's no chance to have this usb audio card working on ubuntu, may I have a list of high quality usb audio cards which for sure are supported by ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.alsa.devel/102869), flick the little switch on the bottom marked EXT from * to **. No idea what this means but the device will now be recognised and work in Ubuntu.